# UIAlertView with one text field (for login purpose)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitextfield, uialertview

When i pull the `tableView` downwards, an `alertView` should appear with a login text field.
The alert has to come but the `textField` is not to be selected.
Once i click on this `textField`, then the keyboard should appear.

For this i am using this code:

```
- (void)toggleCells:(UIRefreshControl*)refreshControl
{
    message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Create a new list"
                                                      message:@""
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [message setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    [message setTag:1001];
    //[message textFieldAtIndex:0].delegate = self;

    [refreshControl beginRefreshing];
    [message show];
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
    //...
}
```

Comment: so... the `textField` gets selected as soon as the `alertView` is displayed. is this your issue? any other issue? one quick fix can be: `[[message textFieldAtIndex:0] resignFirstResponder];` (but yeah, this technique sucks)

Comment: i have used like this but first keyboard is appearing then after it is hiding..i don't want like this to come..first alert has to be come center of the view.. when i select the textfield on alertview then alert has to move up.. then keyboard has to be appear...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"SayWhat" message:@"Please enter Email address" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    av.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [av setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    [[av textFieldAtIndex:0] setPlaceholder:@"Email address"];
    [[av textFieldAtIndex:0] setDelegate:self];

[av show];
[[av textFieldAtIndex:0] resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: when the alertview is appearing the textfield is selected parallely keyboard is also appearing.. i don't want like this..first the alerview has to come. once if i select the textfield on the uialertview then the keyboard has to be appear..

Answer (score 0):

try: (*not so nice but a quick-fix*)

```
message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Create a new list"
                                     message:nil
                                    delegate:self
                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                           otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

[message setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
[message setTag:1001];
[[message textFieldAtIndex:0] setDelegate:self]; //you'll surely need it later

[message show];

[[message textFieldAtIndex:0] resignFirstResponder]; //after showing the alertView
```

NOTE: The method above ain't really nice.

---

### Alternative Method:

**NOTE: declare "`BOOL skipAlertTextField;`" in the `.h`**

```
- (void)toggleCells:(UIRefreshControl*)refreshControl {
    //...
    message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Create a new list"
                                         message:nil
                                        delegate:self
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                               otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    [message setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    [message setTag:1001];
    [[message textFieldAtIndex:0] setDelegate:self];

    skipAlertTextField = YES;  //important
    [message show];
    //...
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if(textField.tag == 1001 && skipAlertTextField) {
        skipAlertTextField = NO;
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: ok yar..working fine .but alertview is not coming at the center.... it is displaying at the top when it is appearing..

Comment: @gajendra : hm... the `alertView` doesn't center. seems to be an issue. anyways... **updated answer** with alternative technique

Comment: @gajendra : sure, i'll check but did this answer help?